# Merge two dataframes with interval data in one of them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

As input I have two dataframes:

```
data1 = [{'code':100}, {'code':120}, {'code':110}]
data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

   code
 0   100
 1   120
 2   110

data2 = [{'category':1, 'l_bound':99, 'r_bound':105},{'category':2, 'l_bound':107, 'r_bound':110},{'category':3, 'l_bound':117, 'r_bound':135}]
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

   category  l_bound  r_bound
0         1       99      105
1         2      107      110
2         3      117      135
```

I want to get in the end the following dataframe, with additional column in the first dataframe as a category number if the code lies in the corresponding interval:

```
    code   category
 0   100          1
 1   120          3
 2   110          2
```

Intervals are random and the original dataframes are pretty big. Looping with itertuples is too slow. Any pythonic solutions?

Comment: pure python - https://eval.in/928533

Comment: @AntonvBR I haven't looked closely at the example, but the problem (and answers) between the two seem identical...

Comment: **Useful observation**: The solutions below might not work if the data are not in a proper format. Make sure that `data1` and `data2` are integers. There also might be mixed formats in some columns of the original datasets (e.g. `'code': '123a'`). To get rid of it just add `data1 = data1[pd.to_numeric(data1['code'], errors='coerce').notnull()]
data1['code'] = pd.to_numeric(data1['code'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recreate the dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

data1 = [{'code':100}, {'code':120}, {'code':113}]
data2 = [{'category':1, 'l_bound':99, 'r_bound':105},
         {'category':2, 'l_bound':107, 'r_bound':110},
         {'category':3, 'l_bound':117, 'r_bound':135}]

data1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
data2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
```

@cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ answer (**prefered**), follow duplicate link:

```
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(data2['l_bound'], data2['r_bound'], closed='both')
category = data2.loc[idx.get_indexer(data1.code), 'category']

data1['category'] = category.values
```

Here is a different approach. Create a map with value in range and categories.

```
# Create a map
d = {i:k for k,v in data2.set_index('category').to_dict('i').items() 
     for i in range(v['l_bound'],v['r_bound']+1)}

# Use map to add new column
data1['category'] = data1.code.map(d)
```

Finally

```
print(data1)
```

Returns:

```
   code  category
0   100       1.0
1   120       3.0
2   113       NaN
```

---

If you want int we can do this:

```
data1.code.map(d).fillna(-1).astype(int) # -1 meaning no match
```

And we get:

```
   code  category
0   100         1
1   120         3
2   113        -1
```

Comment: I dont know why, but IntervalIndex does not seem to work. I have an error" AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'IntervalIndex'"

Comment: Maybe you don’t have the latest pandas version.

Comment: Yeah, that's true.